# DDoS prevention (LOIC doesn't do the job anymore)

Tags: ddos

We are about to launch a important webservice. We must test it for DDoS. From other questions/answers here I learned about `LOIC`. Downloaded, tried, but my apache refuses it.

What other ready made tools are out there so I could CRITICALLY test our serwice?

Any good tutorials on how to do it via `shell`/`bash`?

Comment: See: http://serverfault.com/questions/2107/tools-for-load-testing-http-servers

Comment: LOIC is a joke,  the only reason why it worked is because hundreds of thousands of people where running it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try tools like Seige, BoNSI from Backtrack, these are easy to use and "program name -help" should guide you.
If you are looking something commercial then http://blitz.io is another option.